# Не понимаю, откуда что берется

Tags: python

```
 def task1(x):
     result = 0
     nums = [3, 5]
     for number in range(x):
         if any(number % k == 0 for k in nums):
             result += number
     print(task1(1000) + "\n")
```

Не могу понять, откуда берется `number`, `k`

Объясните пожалуйста, только начинаю учить *Python*, поэтому, по возможности, как для совсем дурачка.

Comment: Их создают циклы `for`, по очереди подставляя значения из коллекции, стоящей после `in`.

Answer (score 1):

Это стандартная запись перебора всех элементов коллекции - такой записью мы экономим создание переменной, которая нужна только в обработке цикла. В общем виде:

```
for element in collection
```

Comment: Это сразу и создание цикла, и создание переменной для обхода элементов.